# Strange SQL Server 2008 behavior while using XLOCK and ROWLOCK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote this script without `COMMIT` in a new Query window (Query1):

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription]
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Region] WITH(XLOCK,ROWLOCK)
WHERE RegionID = 3
```

and in another query window I write this script without COMMIT (Query2):

```
BEGIN TRAN 
SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription]
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Region] WITH(XLOCK,ROWLOCK)
WHERE RegionID = 1
```

Everything is OK, when I run Query1 and then Query2 I can select row with `RegioID=1`. But if I write the first query this way (Query3):

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription]
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Region] WITH(XLOCK,ROWLOCK)
WHERE RegionID = 3 OR RegionID = 4
```

...and add `RegionID = 4` in result, I can't run Query2. Why wheras Query2 result does not has intersect with Query3 I can't run it?

Comment: Make sure you have a "unique" index on RegionID, and make sure the row actually exists.  Without a unique index, the right lock can't be taken. Nor can it be taken if the rows doesn't exist.  For example, if you have a unique index on region id, and rows 1 and 3 exist, you can start two separate transactions, and if one locks 1 and the other locks 3, they can do that at the same time. Likewise, you can simultaneously lock one non-existing row, such as 4. However, if you try to lock another row that does not exist, such as 5, it will fail because of 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd query has an OR which most likely means that a scan is happening. The scan will be blocked by `RegionID = 1`

If you run this, it should run OK.

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription]
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Region] WITH(XLOCK,ROWLOCK)
WHERE RegionID = 4

SELECT [RegionID], [RegionDescription]
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Region] WITH(XLOCK,ROWLOCK)
WHERE RegionID = 3
```

The alternative is that you still have query 1 transaction open...

Edit:

I can't reproduce it (SQL Server 2008 R2 x64 developer). I get an index seek on query 3.

However, in my first iteration I forgot a PRIMARY KEY on my table and query1 blocked query2 because it was a table scan. Which backs up my answer above mostly

Edit 2:

I can't get either Query 2 or Query 3 to block each other (no matter which runs first)

After comments:

- A scan places an XLOCK per scanned row
- OR is often non-SARGable: AND is OK. (OR has some [optimisations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152574/why-isnull-is-twice-slow-as-coalesce-same-query/6152689#6152689)) though)

Comment: Thanks.Dies it means that "OR" , "AND" operand cause table scan?every where in every query? Why Table scan cause table lock?Is it NORMAL?

Comment: @Nima: Table scan takes an XLOCK per row. AND is OK. OR is often non-SARGable

Comment: I wonder why your sql server does not block Query2 after running Query3.Do you use sepecial settings or version?can you test on another version?thanks

Comment: @Nima: Same on SQL Server 2005 SP3 too x86 Enterprise